# android toggle button state always true

Tags: android, togglebutton

Been trying to use a `ToggleButton` to act as a bookmark kind of thing in my application. I am using this for the first time. I have declared my toggle button under `onCreateView()` as below:

```
 bmark = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.bmark);
        bmark.setChecked(false);
```

I am trying to just toggle the state and show a `Toast` message! I tried the below:

```
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        bmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean status;
                if (bmark.isChecked()) status = true;
                else status = false;
                Log.w("Bmark status",String.valueOf(status));
                if (status) {
                    bmark.setChecked(false);
                    Log.w("Bmark after true",String.valueOf(bmark.isChecked()));
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bookmark removed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    bmark.setChecked(true);
                    Log.w("Bmark after false",String.valueOf(bmark.isChecked()));
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Post Bookmarked..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });
```

Every time I press the button, the status is initially read "true", although I've set it to "false". After I call `setChecked(false)`, it also becomes false. But when I click it again, it again reads "true" and instead of "false"

I dont know why its happening like this. I just want to toggle it every time I click it. Pls help me out! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: FYI the accepted answer is not the optimal solution as it requires handling a boolean flag for keeping track of the status.

Comment: status in answer is additional because was in orginal code, maybe it is used in different place, so have nothing to optimal or not.

Comment: @MaciejSikora How is it used in a different place if it's a local variable in `onClick()`? None of your comments make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change code to:

```
if (bmark.isChecked()){ 
status = true;
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Post Bookmarked..!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else {
status = false;
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bookmark removed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Toggle changes self checked status, You done that again so status was changed two times.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're inverting the state of your button by the `setChecked()` calls in `onClick()`.

Use an `OnCheckedChangeListener` instead of an `OnClickListener`, so you don't have to bother with keeping track of the status:

```
bmark.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // checked
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Post Bookmarked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // not checked
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bookmark removed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be switching the button *back* to what it was previously in your statements. If you stop changing the button's state in the onClickListener, it should work just fine.

```
 private boolean bmarkStatus = false;
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    bmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             bmarkStatus = bmark.isChecked();
             if (bmark.isChecked()) Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bookmark removed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             else Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bookmark added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
 }
```